# Wordpress category page, multiple custom post types using standard category, when click how to only show category from post type

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomie

I have multiple custom post types all using 1 taxonomy 'category' this is the blog and a few other custom posts.

I have a menu that only shows links to categories that only if have post in the current custom post type.

I would like to click the link and go to the category page for that category but only show post that are 1, in that category (this is working) 2, post that are only in the previous custom post type(not working.

Im thinking one solution is to pass a variable that stores the custom post type and the query out only category in that passed var.

so far my I have this php for my menu, I want a user to click on the category and only seen post in that category and in to the custom post type.

```
<?php
  if(sizeof($my_categories)) { ?>
    <h6>show only posy cats of post type test</h6>
    <?php
        foreach ($my_categories as $term_id) {
            $category = get_term_by('id', $term_id, 'category');
            if($category->slug!="all-articles") {
            ?>
                 <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->term_id) ?>">
           <?php echo $category->name; ?>
      </a></li>
            <?php
            }
        }
    }
    
?>
```